# Tabs fragment fetch data every time I change tab

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tabs

activity_profile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@drawable/stalker_background" >
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/VPSlider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="175dp"
            />


            <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
                android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />

                    <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

            </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

ProfileActivity.java

```
package com.stalker.androidapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.Session;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.stalker.adapters.ViewPagerAdapter;
import com.stalker.objects.HomeSliderClassForAdapter;
import com.stalker.objects.LikeCategorySummaryResult;
import com.stalker.objects.StoryResult;
import com.stalker.objects.eStoryType;

public class ProfileActivity extends FragmentActivity {

AsyncTask<String, String, String> StoryResponse;
public String storyResponseString;

TextView tv;
public String UserId;
String UserName;
String AccessToken;
ViewPager VPSlider;
public LikeCategorySummaryResult interestResult;
FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
StoryResult Stories = new StoryResult();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    VPSlider = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.VPSlider);




    // /////////////////////////

    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(),
            android.R.id.tabcontent);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator(
                    getResources().getString(R.string.interest)),
            InterestTabFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator(
                    getResources().getString(R.string.interaction)),
            InteractionTabFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator(
                    getResources().getString(R.string.hangout)),
            HangoutTabFragment.class, null);

    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

            InterestTabFragment tabOneFrgment = (InterestTabFragment) fragmentManager
                    .findFragmentByTag("tab1");

            InteractionTabFragment tabTwoFrgment = (InteractionTabFragment) fragmentManager
                    .findFragmentByTag("tab2");

            HangoutTabFragment tabThreeFrgment = (HangoutTabFragment) fragmentManager
                    .findFragmentByTag("tab3");

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();

            if (tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("tab1")) {
                if (tabOneFrgment != null) {
                    if (tabTwoFrgment != null) {
                        fragmentTransaction.hide(tabTwoFrgment);
                    }
                    if (tabThreeFrgment != null) {
                        fragmentTransaction.hide(tabThreeFrgment);
                    }                       
                    fragmentTransaction.show(tabOneFrgment);
                }
            } else if (tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("tab2")) {
                if (tabTwoFrgment != null) {
                    if (tabOneFrgment != null) {
                        fragmentTransaction.hide(tabOneFrgment);
                    }
                    if (tabThreeFrgment != null) {
                        fragmentTransaction.hide(tabThreeFrgment);
                    }
                    fragmentTransaction.show(tabTwoFrgment);
                }
            } else {
                if (tabThreeFrgment != null) {
                    if (tabOneFrgment != null) {
                        fragmentTransaction.hide(tabOneFrgment);
                    }
                    if (tabTwoFrgment != null) {
                        fragmentTransaction.hide(tabTwoFrgment);
                    }
                    fragmentTransaction.show(tabThreeFrgment);
                }
            }

            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
    });


    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        // Get the user's data
        AccessToken = session.getAccessToken();
        makeStoriesRequest(session);
    }



}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.stalker_profile_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

private void makeStoriesRequest(final Session session) {

    String URL = "http://..../";
    JSONObject UserStory;
    JSONObject ProfileStoryString = new JSONObject();
    StoryResponse = new RequestTask().execute(URL);
    try {
        storyResponseString = StoryResponse.get();
        UserStory = new JSONObject(storyResponseString);
        ProfileStoryString = UserStory.getJSONObject("StoryResult");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        try {
            // j = new JSONObject(responseString);
            Stories = gson.fromJson(ProfileStoryString.toString(),
                    StoryResult.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("my", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.e("My App", "Could not parse malformed JSON: \""
                + storyResponseString + "\"" + t.getMessage());
    }

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, getSlider());

    VPSlider.setAdapter(adapter);

}


@Override
protected void onResumeFragments() {
    super.onResumeFragments();

}


}
```

I have this fragment activity on which I'm showing tabs. I have three tabs. For now I have only added code inside InterestTabFragment.java

```
package com.stalker.androidapp;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.stalker.adapters.CategoryLVAdapter;
import com.stalker.objects.LikeCategorySummaryResult;

public class InterestTabFragment extends Fragment{

View view;
String access_token;

AsyncTask<String, String, String> FirstResponse;
public String responseString;
JSONObject joiningYear;
HorizontalListView listview;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.interest_tab_fragment, container, false);

    listview = (HorizontalListView) view.findViewById(R.id.LVCategory);


        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            // Get the user's data
            access_token = session.getAccessToken();
            makeInterestRequest(session);
        }

    return view;
}


private void makeInterestRequest(final Session session) {
    access_token = session.getAccessToken();
    String URL =     "http://...";


    JSONObject HomeCardString = new JSONObject();
    FirstResponse = new RequestTask().execute(URL);
    try {
        responseString = FirstResponse.get();
        joiningYear = new JSONObject(responseString);
        HomeCardString = joiningYear.getJSONObject("LikeCategorySummaryResult");
//          HomeCardString = TestApiResult.getJSONObject("UserHomeResult");         
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {       
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        try
        {
//              j = new JSONObject(responseString);
            ((ProfileActivity)getActivity()).interestResult =     gson.fromJson(HomeCardString.toString(), LikeCategorySummaryResult.class);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.i("myyyy", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.e("My App", "Could not parse malformed JSON: \"" + responseString + "\"" +    t.getMessage());
    }

    CategoryLVAdapter adapter = new CategoryLVAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.category_item_template,     ((ProfileActivity)getActivity()).interestResult.categories);

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

//      listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}


}
```

This code works ok. But when I goto my second tab and then return to first tab. It load data again. but I want it to just show previous fragment don't load it again.

Link to a nice tutorial will also be helpful, but I am already following [this](http://learnncode.wordpress.com/2013/12/18/how-to-use-tabwidget-with-fragments/) tutorial but it is not working as I was expecting it to work.

Comment: do any of these  `if (tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("tab1"))` work and make you go into them?

Comment: But actually, what I think is that it is the default behaviour of tabhost which worked not the code inside these if statements. As if they were working they must not load data again and again, as described in android fragment lifecycle and other various questions.

Comment: ok my last suggestion is: move `Session session =Session.getActiveSession();if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {// Get the user's data access_token = session.getAccessToken(); makeInterestRequest(session);}` from `onCreateView` to `onCreate()` and also  `CategoryLVAdapter adapter = new CategoryLVAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.category_item_template,     ((ProfileActivity)getActivity()).interestResult.categories); listview.setAdapter(adapter);` to oncreaView

Comment: OnCreate of FragmentActivity OR Fragment?

Comment: all change must be done in fragment.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to 3rd tab then go to the 2nd or 1st tab then 1st will be recreated and call onCreate, that is the default behavior of fragment. But going to just 2nd tab and then back to 1st tab will not recreate the 1st tab. I have made some changes in the *InterestTabFragment.java* below only in onCreate. See if it helps, if not then notify me, I may try again. Thanks.....

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.interest_tab_fragment, container, false);

    listview = (HorizontalListView) view.findViewById(R.id.LVCategory);

        if(((ProfileActivity)getActivity()).interestResult.categories == null){
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
                // Get the user's data
                access_token = session.getAccessToken();
                makeInterestRequest(session);
        }
        } else {
            CategoryLVAdapter adapter = new CategoryLVAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.category_item_template,     ((ProfileActivity)getActivity()).interestResult.categories);

            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }


    return view;
}
```

Comment: Same thing was on my mind, But can't we just hide and then show fragment? I have implemented facebook login through facebook guide. They made fragments in their guide. And following that tutorial I made more fragments and they just load data once. Just show that fragment.

Comment: Sorry, no idea about hiding the fragment. Whenever I need to load data once and show them in fragments, I just made the data source static variable and show them with the above checking.....