# How to prevent Fragment from loading data every time from server when swiping Tabs in TabLayout in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I am a newbie with `Fragments`. I have 5 different `Fragments`in my `TabLayout`. In each fragment I am loading data from the server.

My problem is as follows:
When the first fragment loads it calls the function and loads data from the server and displays on the `RecyclerView`.

Then When I swipe to the second tab the server data loads and so on. But when I swipe again to say fragment one the data is loading again from the server and the `RecyclerView` needs to be set again.

Is there anyway where I can load the server data only once (without saving it to a local database) and set the `recyclerview` only once so that no matter how many times I swipe the tab the data does not load again? I have referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337570/tabs-fragment-fetch-data-every-time-i-change-tab) but i really didnt understand how to solve my problem.I am posting a snippet of my code.

TabActivity

```
public class TabActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ViewPager viewpager;
Toolbar toolbar;
TabLayout tablayout;
ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_activity);
    initialize();




}

private void initialize() {
    viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    tablayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    viewPagerAdapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewpager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    tablayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    tablayout.setupWithViewPager(viewpager);

}


}

 class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:return LocatedEvents.newInstance();

        case 1:return QrCodeScanner.newInstance();
        case 2:return NewsFeed.newInstance();

        case 3:return CreatePoll.newInstance();
        case 4:return MyProfile.newInstance();
    }
    return NewsFeed.newInstance();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 5;
}
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return "Tab " + (position + 1);
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {

}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

}
}
```

NewsFeed Fragment

```
public class NewsFeed extends Fragment {
@Nullable

public static NewsFeed newInstance() {
    return new NewsFeed();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsfeed_fragment, container, false);
    load_data();
    return view;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid creating new Fragments every time in

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
 switch (position) {
  case 0:
   return LocatedEvents.newInstance();

  case 1:
   return QrCodeScanner.newInstance();
  case 2:
   return NewsFeed.newInstance();

  case 3:
   return CreatePoll.newInstance();
  case 4:
   return MyProfile.newInstance();
 }
 return NewsFeed.newInstance();
}
```

Make an array of fragments and pass it to your Adapter.Something like this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

 initFragments();

}

private void initFragments() {

  ArrayList < Fragment > fragmentArrayList = new ArrayList < > ();

  fragmentArrayList.add(LocatedEvents.newInstance());
  fragmentArrayList.add(QrCodeScanner.newInstance());
  fragmentArrayList.add(NewsFeed.newInstance());
  fragmentArrayList.add(MyProfile.newInstance();

   viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragmentArrayList); viewpager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter); tablayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(viewPagerAdapter); tablayout.setupWithViewPager(viewpager);
  }
```

And in your adapter change it to

```
private ArrayList < Fragment > fragments;

  public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList < Fragment > fragments) {
   super(fm);
   this.fragments = fragments;
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
   return fragments.get(position);
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
   return fragments.size();
  }
```